# Average date difference in QueryDSL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I have an entity with a Date object representing last activity. I would like to query the average idle time. So in SQL something like:

```
SELECT AVG(NOW() - idle_date) FROM mytable WHERE ....
```

I tried to calculate the difference like this:

```
query.singleResult(
    Expressions.dateOperation(
        Long.class, 
        Ops.DateTimeOps.DIFF_SECONDS,
        DateExpression.currentDate(),
        myTable.idleDate
    )
);
```

But that does not allow me to do an average on the result, only min and max.

How can I express this average on a date/time difference (in seconds) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a `NumberTemplate` object; something along these lines should do what you need: `NumberTemplate.create(Double.class, "AVG(NOW() - {0})", myTable.idleDate);`

Comment: I used `NumberTemplate.create(Double.class, "{0} - {1}", DateExpression.currentDate(), myTable.idleSince).avg()` and this works fine. (I took the liberty to edit your comment so I can mark it as the correct solution)

Comment: In fact, this is not working as expected. This code does give a numeric result but it doesn't make sense and is certainly not a number of seconds. I tried to replace {0} - {1} with TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, {1}, {0}) but that is not a JPA expression and therefore fails.

Comment: Is `idleDate` represented as a `java.sql.Timestamp` or a `java.sql.Date`? If it's a `java.sql.Timestamp`, there's a `DateTimeExpression.currentDate()` which may help. Alternatively, perhaps it's possible to use a `DateTemplate` and handle the result once you've got it Java side. Sorry this didn't work out.